# "Persistent" Switches in WPF/XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, vbscript

I have a program whose behavior should change based on whether it has been run more than one time. Is it possible to have a switch that retains its value between each run that tells the program what to do?

For example (obviously pseudocode):

```
if (first_run){
    make splash screen say "Welcome, Newcomer!";
    give a tour of program on boot;
}
else {
    make splash screen say "Hello again!";
    do not give tour;
}
```

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10871837/metro-xaml-c-detect-installation-and-or-first-run), but apparently `Windows.Storage`'s minimum supported client is Windows 8, and I want my application to be available for Windows 7 users. In addition, using [the code suggested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx#Y0) by the accepted answerer throws a `Type Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer is not defined` error.

I'm new to XAML and WPF, so forgive me if this is simple; I Googled and found no relevant results (I still don't even know if/how one can embed C# in WPF, since I don't see an option for it in VS2013).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHat about the plain old Settings which are to be found in the project properties. Define an int key there and increment it on each run, e.g. on the initialize event.
See the documentation for details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patrickdanino/archive/2008/07/23/user-settings-in-wpf.aspx